# Is the null space of a linear transformation the same as the space of eigenvectors with zero eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Null space of linear transformation is defined as the set of vectors, which are mapped to the zero vector by the transformation.

Eigenspace is the set of vectors that are mapped to scaled multiples themselves by a linear transformation.

Clearly, eigenvectors which have a corresponding eigenvalue of 0 are part of the null space, as these vectors are multiplied to zero by the eigenvalue.

My question is: **are these vector spaces the same?**

Can there be a vector that is mapped to zero vector by the linear transformation, but is *not* an eigenvector?

Or is the null space of a transformation precisely the set of eigenvectors with a corresponding zero eigenvalue?

Comment: They're the same, by definition. The $\lambda$-eigenspace of $A$ is the set of vectors $v$ such that $(A - \lambda I) v = 0$. If $\lambda = 0$, then this is the set of vectors $v$ such that $(A - 0 I) v = A v = 0$, which is exactly the nullspace of $A$.

Answer (score 4):

They are the same subspace of $E$ for $A:E\to E,$ for the reason you gave.

But for $A:E\to F\ne E,$ only the null space has a meaning.

Note also that eigenvectors (for some eigenvalue, for $A:E\to E$) are $\ne0$ by definition, hence their set is not exactly equal to the corresponding eigen*subspace*.

Comment: The second point is well made.

Comment: Thank you, could you specify what you mean by $E$?

Comment: As written in my two first sentences, the vector space $E$ is the domain of the linear map $A.$